# How to do a rolling count of values grouping by date python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have a table of data like below and I want to try do a rolling count that takes the date in the group by and the values of dates prior.

Table of data:

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 123 |
| 2/1/2020 | 432 |
| 2/1/2020 | 5234 |
| 4/1/2020 | 543 |
| 5/1/2020 | 645 |
| 6/1/2020 | 231 |

My desired output is something like this:

| Date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 1 |
| 2/1/2020 | 3 |
| 4/1/2020 | 4 |
| 5/1/2020 | 5 |
| 6/1/2020 | 6 |

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work on how I want it do it.

`df[['id','date']].groupby('date').cumcount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes for correct ordering if aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.groupby('Date').size().cumsum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
        Date  count
0 2020-01-01      1
1 2020-01-02      3
2 2020-01-04      4
3 2020-01-05      5
4 2020-01-06      6
```